# Should I create a composer umbrella package?

Tags: php, package, versioning, grouping, composer-php

For our custom CMS we have extracted everything out to different modules, this includes everything from the user system, the roles manager, the page editor, the theme system etc.

Several of these are required for the system to run in the first place.

So our composer.json already has about 15 different "requirements" in place.

Now, what I am wondering is, would it be a better idea to create an umberella package, this package would not contain anything itself, but it would require all the different bits and pieces.

So, instead of having 15 different require we could just have

```
{
    "require": {
        "cms/core": "1.0.*"
    }
}
```

The downside I see if that for every update to any package under the umbrella we must update the version for the umbrella package, meaning that while the highest part in the framework might only be 2.7.34 the umbrella could well be at 26.12.116 or similar.

If we did create an umbrella package how should we manage this? just have the package require all packages as `*`? would we run into compatibility issues doing this?

Comment: You should not only guess-ask but also try and then report back how that worked for you. Have you tried to create such an umbrella package? Did it work even? Does the autoloader still work for you? And all these detailed questions that will only pop-up if you confront yourself with the actual work. So test your own before asking generally, the details will come from alone and users here can't say for your code. Also about the version numbering: Decide how *you* want to version the main package

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r I agree, and I will report back how it works, I was hoping to crowdsource issues/suggestions with doing it this way, much like you have a group meeting to discuss a project before you start it.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not good for such group meetings.  It's bare Q and A with a low noise ratio, that means: No (or very very little it at all) discussion, no opinion forming. For a good reason. Regarding versioning, here is a place where some folks have formed an opinion already: http://semver.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it and set the [type](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#type) to metapackage also if it really contains no files. It might indeed make your user's life easier.

What I would recommend though is that you require: `1.0.*` of every sub-package, and then when you bump everything to `1.1` you change to `1.1.*` and tag a `cms/core 1.1.0`. That's if you have all the versions more or less in sync.

If every component is versioned independently, then it gets a bit harder. At that point maybe using `~1.0` requirements would be best. That will allow updates up (but not including) to 2.0, which means you can make sure things at least work together. But there is no silver bullet there really, it depends on the case, and you should try to gain a bit more understanding of versioning practices before you proceed.